# Teechart:Adding a drilldown to a teechart horizontalbar

Tags: java, json, eclipse, teechart

I am using teecharts. I have successfully populated a chart of type TCHart with horizontal bar series of data. I was wondering if there was a way to add a drill down to the chart. Can I click on an individual bar to create a popup window with more information?

```
private TChart chart = new TChart();
Series barSeries = new HorizBar();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SeriesMouseListener` for this as follows:

```
Series barSeries = new HorizBar(tChart1.getChart());
barSeries.fillSampleValues();

barSeries.addSeriesMouseListener(new SeriesMouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void seriesClicked(SeriesMouseEvent arg0) {
        // show info here for the arg0.getValueIndex()
    }
});
```